# How to Create Math Quiz Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have to create a Math Quiz for a school project. I already created the questions and answers. I just don't know how to get them to show one question at a time. I have to show each question one by one as you answer them.

I also need to use different types of questions such as Multiple Choice, Question with Narrative Response, Question with Image Selection, Fill in the blank, etc.

So I need help with displaying the questions one at a time, displaying a scoreboard, showing the user if they got the question right or wrong before the next question appears, showing a pass or fail message if they got at least 80% or not, and giving the user an option to retake the quiz at the end.

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Math Quiz!</title>
<link href ="quizCSS.css" rel ="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<script src = "MathQuiz.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>


<body>
<h1>Take the Quiz!</h1>

<form id = "quiz" name = "quiz">


<div id="q1">
<p class = "questions">1) What is 2 + 2?</p>
<input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "question1">
<input type="button" onclick="myAnswer1()" value="Submit Answer">

<script>


var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;
function myAnswer1() {
if(question1 == 4){
document.write("You are correct!");
}
else{
document.write("Wrong Answer!");
}
}
</script>

</div>



<input type="button" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Start Question 1">
<script>
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "block";
}
</script>


<div id="q2">
<p class = "questions">2) What is 3 to the power of 2?</p>
<input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question2" value = "9"> 9<br>
<input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question2" value = "6"> 6<br>
<input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question2" value = "3"> 3<br>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction2()" value="Start Question 2">
<script>
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("q2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "none";

}
</script>

<div id="q3">
<p class = "questions">3) What is the square root of 25?</p>

<input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question3" value = "5"> 5<br>
<input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question3" value = "525"> 525<br>
</div>


<input type="button" onclick="myFunction3()" value="Start Question 3">
<script>
function myFunction3() {
  document.getElementById("q3").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q2").style.display = "none";

}
</script>

<div id="q4">
<p class = "questions">4) What is the square root of 81?</p>

<input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question4" value = "9"> 9<br>
<input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question4" value = "7"> 7<br>
</div>


<input type="button" onclick="myFunction4()" value="Start Question 4">
<script>
function myFunction4() {
  document.getElementById("q4").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q3").style.display = "none";

}
</script>

<div id="q5">
<p class = "questions">5) Which shape has a right angle?</p>

<input type = "image" id = "pic" name = "question5" value = img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Blue_Square.svg" width="100" height="100"><br>
<input type = "image" id = "pic" name = "question5" value = img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Green_equilateral_triangle_point_up.svg" width="100" height="100"><br>
<input type = "image" id = "pic" name = "question5" value = img src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/310000/velka/red-circle.png" width="100" height="100"><br>
</div>


<input type="button" onclick="myFunction5()" value="Start Question 5">
<script>
function myFunction5() {
  document.getElementById("q5").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q4").style.display = "none";

}
</script>


<input id = "button" type = "button" value = "I'm finished!" onclick = "check();">


</form>

<div id = "after_submit">
<p id = "number_correct"></p>
<p id = "message"></p>
<img id = "picture">
</div>

<script src = "MathQuiz.js" defer></script>
</body>



</html>
```

This is my Javascript

```
function check(){

    var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;
    var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;
    var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;
    var question4 = document.quiz.question4.value;
    var question5 = document.quiz.question5.value;
    var correct = 0;

    if (question1 == "4") {
        correct++;
}
    if (question2 == "9") {
        correct++;
}   
    if (question3 == "5") {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question4 == "9") {
        correct++;
}   
    if (question5 == "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Blue_Square.svg") {
        correct++;
    }


    var pictures = ["img/win.gif", "img/meh.jpeg", "img/lose.gif"];
    var messages = ["You pass the quiz", "You fail the quiz"];
    var score;

    if (correct == 0) {
        score = 4;
    }

    if (correct > 0 && correct < 3) {
        score = 3;
    }

    if (correct == 3) {
        score = 2;
    }

    if (correct == 4) {
        score = 1;
    }

    if (correct == 5) {
        score = 0;
    }



    document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[score];
    document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML = "You got " + correct + " correct.";
    document.getElementById("picture").src = pictures[score];
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is way too broad for here. You really should limit your questions to a specific issue. What have you tried in order to accomplish the list of things you listed? Also, since this is homework, you could reach out to the teacher if you having trouble.

Comment: I found out how to hide one div element. But idk how to hide all div elements, then get them to show one by one as the user answers questions. Btw, my teacher never answers emails unfortunately :/ Update: I found out how to hide them all using CSS. Now just need to display them one by one while hiding the previously answered question

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this. With js and css you can change the value of the element `display: block;` of the each question to `hidden`, changing them back to `block` whenever the user has to answer the question - while one is `block`, all the other should be hidden.

To do that try using the

`document.getElementsByID("myDiv1").style.display = "hidden";`

and

`document.getElementsByID("myDiv2").style.display = "block";`

respectively, where `myDiv1` is an example of a div you'll want to wrap around the questions that should be hidden and `myDiv2` the div wrapping the current question.

For more information on how to do this, check [w3schools Style display Property reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp).

Comment: Thanks! I used CSS to hide the display. Now just need to display them one by one while hiding the previously answered questions

Answer (score 0):

Jquery to the rescue!

Simply use `$("#id").show()` and `hide()`:

```
var q = 1; //question #
function start() {
    $("#q2").hide();
    $("#q3").hide();
    //add more for more questions
}
function nextQ() {
    q++;
    update();
}
function update() {
    //hide all
    $("#q1").hide();
    $("#q2").hide();
    $("#q3").hide();
    //show next Q
    $("#q"+q).show();
}
```

HTML **snippet**:

```html
<button onclick="start();">Start</button>
<div id="q1">
    <!-- question -->
    1
    <button onclick="nextQ();">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="q2">
    <!-- question -->
    2
    <button onclick="nextQ();">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="q3">
    <!-- question -->
    3
    <button onclick="nextQ();">Next</button>
</div>
```

P.S. Use `onload` attribute to run `start()` as soon as the page loads.

Comment: But how do I make it display if the user got the question right or wrong before they move on to the next question?

Comment: `if (Question Data Variable == Correct Answer) pts++;` or something like that